# Search result source exclude read only sites

Tags: search-results, kql-query

I am looking for a way to set up two search result sources, one that should exclude all content from any site collection that have been set as Read only and another that should only show content from those site collections. 
Excluding the Read Only site collections from the search index will solve part one but make it impossible to achieve part two

I have looked into running a powershell script every hour or so that will collect the site collection paths and inject those into the result sources, but I guess that will not scale once I have +1000 Read Only site collections

Comment: Suggestion from Mikael Svensson: update the title of the Read Only sites to be prefixed with "ReadOnly_" and use that in the search query